# How to reset lost administrative password?

Tags: settings

I can not update because the person who set up my PC is out of the country and he didn't give ,me the "Authentication" password

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know your Administrative password and need to perform a system update/upgrade, you may want to reset it. You can read about how to do it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).